# how to map F4 run a no name file on vim?

Tags: python, vim

I add a line in _vimrc .

```
map <F4> :w<cr>:!python %<cr>
```

If  the file contain  name ,it can run,if the file is a new edited which contain no name ,when i press <kbd>F4</kbd> ,it can't run .
I  want to make my configuration more smart ,and don't want to save it ,give it a name and press <kbd>F4</kbd>,how can i revise  `map <F4> :w<cr>:!python %<cr>` to make the no name python file to run ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about using `:w !{cmd}`? (This does not require you to save before run the command).

```
:map <F4> :w !python<cr>
```

According to vim `help :w_c`:

> `:[range]w[rite] [++opt] !{cmd}`
>
> ```
>       Execute {cmd} with [range] lines as standard input
>       (note the space in front of the '!').  {cmd} is
>       executed like with ":!{cmd}", any '!' is replaced with
>       the previous command |:!|.
> ```

**NOTE** This will not work as expected if the Python program itself use filename. (For example, `__file__` will yield `'<stdin>'`)

Comment: i test it :one can not write **map <F4> :w !python<cr>** in the _vimrc,and pressF4 to make the no name file run .it is failure.

Comment: @it_is_a_literature, It works as expected (I also tested it with `.vimrc` using vim 7.4 in ubuntu 13.04). See [this screencast I just recorded](http://asciinema.org/a/7061).

Comment: my system is xp+vim ,when i input the command on the bottom of vim and press enter and press F4,it can run ,but when i write it on the _vimrc file(the configuration file) ,press F4 ,have no effect!

Comment: @it_is_a_literature, I just tested it with Window 7 machine and it worked. I also tested this in Window XP virtual machine, and it worked. Check whether your `_vimrc` is properly loaded.

Comment: it is **:map <F5> :w !python<cr** written into _vimrc ,not **map <F5> :w !python<cr>**  .think falsetru.